# Allow file explorer in Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2

Tags: vb.net, webview2

I have a Winforms app with a webview but the file explorer do not open when fired inside the webview (works fine on browser) i alredy tried the following  :

```
Dim oEnvironment As Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment

Dim opts As CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions = New CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions()

'opts.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--allow-file-access-from-files"
opts.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--disable-web-security"

oEnvironment = Await Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(String.Empty, System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), opts)

Await browser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(environment:=oEnvironment)
```

The page do nor return any error.

How can i give permissions to open that?

**Update**:

I have a file picker like this below, if i drag and drop the files it works, if i click "Browse" nothing appen in the webview (on browser all woks fine)

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `browser.Source = new Uri("file://SomePath/")`? As of now, you're setting the `UserDataFolder`, which doesn't seem related to what you're asking.

Comment: BTW, `--disable-web-security` is not required (or related).

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to achieve. Why do you need access to the file system from a web browser? Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. The following may also be helpful: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks, i have updated my question and added more info about my problem, thanks for the answers